Interpretation of main effects under the presence of interaction terms in fixed-effect models and using plot_predictions
I would like to ask about the following.
I am working with a T=2 panel data, and assuming a model of X1, X2, and X1*X2 estimated with the within estimator, which one would be the more appropriate interpretation of the coefficient on X1?

the effect of X1 on Y conditional on X2=0, or
the effect of X1 on Y conditional on X2 having not changed within entity across time.

In addition, if I use plot_predictions() from "jtools" to make predictions using the above model under particular values of X2 (e.g., "X2" = c(-2,0,2)), should I also interpret as the predicted values of Y assuming when X2 is -2, 0, and 2, or when X2 had decreased by 2, remained constant, and increased by 2?
Thank you so much for your time

"X2 having not changed across time." What does that mean?

"the effect of X1 on Y conditional on X2=0, or" this is a correct interpretation, but problematic when 0 is not part of the domain of X2. E.g when X2 is an inverse speed, then it can't be zero. (see also an example here for cars' fuel efficiencies as function of displacement https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429526/429867#429867)

Apologies for the poor wording. I meant in the context of panel data, after the within transformation, X2 remains unchanged for the entity over time.

In my particular case X2 (height-for-age z-score) has a meaningful interpretation when equals to 0.

You mean, you measure the same subject two times and X2 didn't change, then it has no role in the interaction term X1*X2?

Here you see more interpretations https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590620/

Sorry, I should have given more details on the context in the question. I am looking at the effect of a treatment denoted by the dummy X1, but I suspect the treatment effect is heterogenous in X2. I am familiar with the interpretation of the main effect in pooled models ("the effect of X1 on Y conditional on X2=0"), but I am uncertain as to if the same is true after the data has undergone the within transformation. Is it be more appropriate to say that beta(X1) = treatment effect if X2 didn't change for the entity over time, beta(X1*X2) = treatment effect if X2 increased by 1 unit. Thank you!

"the data has undergone the within transformation" this is not a familiar term to me.

Here you see more interpretations in terms of one of the variables being a moderating effect https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/590620/
You can rewrite $$y = a_0  + a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_1x_2$$ as $$y = a_0   + (a_1+a_3 x_2) x_1 + a_2 x_2$$
and the effect of $x_1$, which is $(a_1+a_3 x_2)$ in this viewpoint, can be seen to depend on $x_2$. The main effect coefficient $a_1$ is the value of this effect when $x_2 = 0$.
You can see it as a sort of intercept. Sometimes this intercept or main effect might have an intuitive interpretation, but other times it might make no sense (also with a shift of variables these intercepts can have any arbitrary location), when $x_2=0$ never occurs or has no realistic interpretation. E.g $x_2$ could be an inverse velocity , or the years counted AD for an entity that didn't exist in 0AD, etc. An example for a related question is here Why is the intercept in multiple regression changing when including/excluding regressors?
